# Cannot connect to Oracle database from php

Tags: php, oracle

This is the code I got from a tutorial,

```
<?php

$db = “(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST =192.168.1.34)(PORT = 1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=orcl)))” ; //gave my corresponding ip

if ($c=OCILogon(“system”, “your database password“, $db))  // gave my corresponding username and password
 {

echo “Successfully connected to Oracle.\n”;

OCILogoff($c);

} else {

$err = OCIError();

echo “Connection failed.” . $err[text];

}


?>
```

I checked on the terminal for ping to this corresponding database, there is ping to this IP(my corresponding IP)

Also I can connect to this database via toad from a windows machine, I am currently using ubuntu

No message is displaying not even `echo “Connection failed.” . $err[text];`

What am I doing wrong please help

Comment: please... change all `“ ”` to regular quotes `"`. those are curly quotes and will kill anything, even weeds. I can foresee people wanting to put an answer and feed off this, but this is off-topic. Voted to close as such.

Comment: *"No message is displaying..."* - Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, and you will start seeing them, being parse errors.

Comment: @Fred -ii I am sorry for the confusion, but I already changed the `“ ”` to `" "`

Comment: @Fred-ii- I did that, now this error `Fatal error: Call to undefined function OCILogon() in /var/www/TestingTabs/test2.php on line 12`.

Comment: are you able to use MySQL rather than Oracle? also please update your code with the quotes you are now using

Answer (score 1):

It seems you dont have php-oracle driver installed in your system, have you checked it? if its not there, download the appropriate one from oracle

```
http://kogentadono.com/2011/11/02/installing-oci8-on-ubuntu/
```

See if this helps